# Inference for the definition of Strictly Increasing Function

Tags: calculus, discrete-mathematics, logic

The definition of strictly increasing function is

```
if x < y, then f(x) < f(y)
```

Then I did some logical inference

```
step 1. x < y --> f(x) < f(y)
step 2. f(x) >= f(y) --> x >= y ... (p-->q equivalent to !q-->!p)
step 3. There is a function F(x), and for all x1, x2 which x1 > x2, F(x1)=F(x2)
step 4. (step 3) makes (step 2) true
step 5. Because (step 2) is equivalent to (step 1), 
        I can say the function is a strictly increasing function.
```

I know the result looks weird and definitely wrong (F(x) is a constant function), but I couldn't find where the problem is. So my question is : which step is wrong and why?

Comment: Where did you get step 2 ? Why did $<$ suddenly turn into $\leq$ ?

Comment: p-->q is equivalent to !q-->!p. So x<y-->f(x)<f(y) is equivalent to !(f(x)<f(y))-->!(x<y) which is f(x)>=f(y) --> x>=y.

Comment: step 4 is wrong because the implication of step 2 does not hold for all x,y when f=F

Comment: @MichalAdamaszek I don't follow. Could you explain more or give a counter example?

Comment: If F is a constant function, x=3 and y=5, then the implication in step 2 fails.

Comment: @MichalAdamaszek I got it. Thank you so much.